How to download Sidekiq Pro (private gem) in pipeline
Sidekiq Pro is a private Ruby gem that requires authorization and, although I've gotten it to work locally, I've been unable to get it to work in the pipeline. I use a yaml file on my repo to define the build process in Github Workflows. The part that involves Sidekiq is as follows:
- name: Build
  env:
    ONE_PASSWORD: ${{ ... }}
    TWO_PASSWORD: ${{ ... }}
    THREE_PASSWORD: ${{ ... }}
  run: |
    docker build ...
    bundle config https://gems.contribsys.com ${{ secrets.SIDEKIQ_KEY }}:${{ secrets.SIDEKIQ_PASS }}

With this configuration I get an unauthorized error. Yet when I "print" the ./bundle/config file via the pipeline (using the cat command in the yaml file) I can see the key and password:
  BUNDLE_GEMS__CONTRIB_SYS__COM: ***:***

Other things I've tried:
- name: Configure Sidekiq
  run: |
    mkdir -p ~./bundle && \
    echo BUNDLE_HTTPS://GEMS__CONTRIBSYS__COM/: ${{ secrets.SIDEKIQ_KEY }}:${{ secrets.SIDEKIQ_PASS }} > ~/.bundle/config

- name: Configure Sidekiq
  run: |
    mkdir -p ~./bundle && \
    echo BUNDLE_HTTPS://GEMS__CONTRIBSYS__COM/: "${{ secrets.SIDEKIQ_KEY }}:${{ secrets.SIDEKIQ_PASS }}" > ~/.bundle/config

- name: Configure Sidekiq
  env:
    SIDEKIQ_KEY: ${{ secrets.SIDEKIQ_KEY }}
    SIDEKIQ_PASS: ${{ secrets.SIDEKIQ_PASS }}
  run: |
    mkdir -p ~./bundle && \
    echo BUNDLE_HTTPS://GEMS__CONTRIBSYS__COM/: ${SIDEKIQ_KEY}:${SIDEKIQ_PASS} > ~/.bundle/config

I've already reviewed their documentation found here, https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/wiki/Commercial-FAQ#how-do-i-debug-a-401-access-denied-error, and it doesn't solve my issue.

https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/issues/3568. I can't say for sure but it seems like your bundle config command might just be slightly off. same suggestion was made Here

@engineersmnky so I tried that and could not get the “bundle” to work. Kept getting “bundle not defined”. I’m putting it in a different spot to see if that’ll work.
